# QTableWidget: Prioritize horizontal space for a specific column

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qtablewidget

I have a QTableWidget that has a column (#3) that needs more space than others.  I want to resize all columns to their contents, and give priority to column #3.  If column #3 pushes the table's width past what's available, I want column #3 to be truncated with '...' without a horizontal scrollBar.

The screenshot below is the simplest example of the behavior I'm chasing, but I've had to manually adjust the column widths.  I want the table to do this automatically.

[image]

The following code shows examples of what I've tried on QTableWidget, but none have worked.  I've provided inline comments on why the following methods do not work:

```
table->horizontalHeader()->setStretchLastSection(true);
table->resizeColumnsToContents();
```

Thank you to anyone who volunteers your time to help me with this.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QTableWidget>
#include <QStringList>
#include <QRect>
#include <QLayout>
#include <QDialog>
#include <QHeaderView>

#include <iostream>

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QDialog* d = new QDialog();
    d->setLayout( new QVBoxLayout() );

    QTableWidget* table = new QTableWidget(1,4);
    QStringList headers = {"1", "2", "3", "4"};
    table->setHorizontalHeaderLabels(headers);

    table->setItem(0, 0, new QTableWidgetItem("1"));
    table->setItem(0, 1, new QTableWidgetItem("22222"));
    table->setItem(0, 2, new QTableWidgetItem("33333333333333333333333333333"));
    table->setItem(0, 3, new QTableWidgetItem("4"));

    // Do nothing
    //
    //   The table exceeds the dimensions of the dialog,
    //   and we get a horizontal scrollbar

    // This also results in a horizontal scrollbar
    //
    //  table->horizontalHeader()->setStretchLastSection(true);

    // Resizing the columns introduces a horizontal scrollbar, and
    // prevents the user from from changing column width
    //
    //  table->resizeColumnsToContents();

    // The table fits, but all columns are equally spaced.
    // (We want column 3 to take up as much space as possible)
    //
    // table->horizontalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView::Stretch);

    // Columns are resized to their contents,
    // but column 3 is not truncated and we get a horizontal scrollBar
    //
    //  table->horizontalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView::ResizeToContents);

    d->layout()->addWidget( table );
    d->show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, try it out

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QTableWidget>
#include <QStringList>
#include <QRect>
#include <QLayout>
#include <QDialog>
#include <QHeaderView>
#include <QScrollBar>

#include <iostream>

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
QApplication a(argc, argv);

QDialog* d = new QDialog();
d->setLayout( new QVBoxLayout() );

QTableWidget* table = new QTableWidget(1,4);
QStringList headers = {"1", "2", "3", "4"};
table->setHorizontalHeaderLabels(headers);

table->setItem(0, 0, new QTableWidgetItem("1"));
table->setItem(0, 1, new QTableWidgetItem("22222"));
table->setItem(0, 2, new QTableWidgetItem("33333333333333333333333333333"));
table->setItem(0, 3, new QTableWidgetItem("4"));

// Do nothing
//
//   The table exceeds the dimensions of the dialog,
//   and we get a horizontal scrollbar

// This also results in a horizontal scrollbar
//
//  table->horizontalHeader()->setStretchLastSection(true);

// Resizing the columns introduces a horizontal scrollbar, and
// prevents the user from changing column width
//

 //resize table
  d->layout()->addWidget( table );
  d->show();

  table->resizeColumnsToContents();

  int tableWidth = table->width();
  int columsWidth = 0;
  int maxColumnWidth = 0;
  int maxColumnIndex = 0;
  int w = 0;

  for(int n = 0; n < table->columnCount(); n++)
  {
      w = table->columnWidth(n);
      columsWidth += w;
      if(w > maxColumnWidth)
      {
          maxColumnWidth = w;
          maxColumnIndex = n;
      }
  }

  if(columsWidth > tableWidth)
  {
      int delta = columsWidth - tableWidth + table->horizontalScrollBar()->height();
      maxColumnWidth -= delta;
      if(maxColumnWidth < 0)
          maxColumnWidth = 0;
      table->setColumnWidth(maxColumnIndex, maxColumnWidth);
  }

// This table fits, but all the columns are equally spaced.
// (We want column 3 to take up as much space as possible)
//
// table->horizontalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView::Stretch);

// Columns are resized to their contents,
// but column 3 is not truncated and we get a horizontal scrollBar
//
//  table->horizontalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView::ResizeToContents);

return a.exec();
```

}

Get back to me if you have any problems with this code.